# Initializing variables in a new method

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExponentExperiment
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int numberOne;
        int B;
        int C;
        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an Integer");
        numberOne = keyBoard.nextInt();
        jordan(numberOne, B);
        carter(numberOne, B, C);
        System.out.println(numberOne + " squared is " + B);
        System.out.println(numberOne + " cubed is " + C);
    }
    public static int jordan(int numberOne, int B)
    {
        B = numberOne * numberOne;
    return B;

    }
    public static int carter(int numberOne, int B, int C)
    {
            C = B * numberOne;
    return C;

    }

}
```

Errors:

H:\ExponentExperiment.java:13: variable B might not have been initialized
        jordan(numberOne, B);
                          ^
H:\ExponentExperiment.java:14: variable C might not have been initialized
        carter(numberOne, B, C);
                             ^
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: You can improve your question by following this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use your return values?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExponentExperiment
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int numberOne;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an Integer");
        numberOne = keyBoard.nextInt();
        b = jordan(numberOne);
        c = carter(numberOne, b);
        System.out.println(numberOne + " squared is " + b);
        System.out.println(numberOne + " cubed is " + c);
    }
    public static int jordan(int numberOne)
    {
        return (numberOne * numberOne);
    }

    public static int carter(int numberOne, int b)
    {
            return (b * numberOne);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java simple types' variables are passed by value, so it is not going to work, ever. 
See: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: _In Java simple types' variables are passed by value_ Not only _simple types_. Java passes everything by value. The only thing which is different between primitives and objects is that, for primitives, java passes primitives by value and, for objects, it passes object _references_ by value.

Comment: That's true, I just simplified my answer.

Answer (score -1):

where you have int B; and int C; in the top of your main method, do

```
  int B = 0; 
  int C = 0;
```

so they are initialized.

Comment: this appears to work. but would declaring the variables as 0 not screw up the program?

Comment: no because when you call the methods, you are going to be using the B and C variables, so it is going to be updating the value of them